# HANA Service Layer : Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, rest, hana

I am trying to call SAP HANA Service Layer through my code but I am stumbling upon the below error : So can anyone please help me on this.

**Error 1st :**

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

**Error 2nd :**

> WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

**Error 3rd :**

> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

**Some more details about the App** - I have created the console app in .NET and it executes on the server [HANA Server is locally accessed as both the servers are in the LAN] Linux & Windows Server.

**One more thing** - My client is not planning to purchase the domain name and SSL certificate for the SAP HANA Service Layer because it will be consumed by my app internally.

The thing is, when I tested the login service via Postman it's working fine and I am getting the session details as well but the same URL is not working through my code so is there anything more I need to do to access the service?

URL - https://172.17.100.35:50000/b1s/v1/Login

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
var credentials = new { UserName = "admin", Password = "", "" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
 
var response = client.PostAsync(url),
                    new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
 
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

// Access variables from the returned JSON object
var appHref = content.links.applications.href;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using self signed certificates you have to accepted them first. that can be done by add it to windows certificates ou by the browser!
if you are making cross-domain calls, you need to change the b1s.config

```
vim /usr/sap/SAPBusinessOne/ServiceLayer/conf/b1s.conf

(...)
"CorsEnable": true,
 "CorsAllowedOrigins": "*"}
```

do note use * in production MODE <-<<<--

Answer (score 3):

For future googlers getting a 500 error response after sending your request to the Login endpoint, disable ExpectContinue.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this code before **postAsync**

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

This avoid the validation of the certificate.